# A better way to test if an macro variable is an valid SAS number or not

Tags: sas

I am working on a SAS macro to validate if a macro variable is **an valid SAS number** or not. My solution is based on `prxmacth()` function:

```
%macro IsSASnumber(number);
%sysfunc(prxmatch(/^-?(?:\d+|\d*\.\d+)(?:e-?\d+)?|\.[a-z]?$/i,&number));
%mend;
```

There are several examples:

```
%put %IsSASnumber(123);
1

%put %IsSASnumber(1.23);
1

%put %IsSASnumber(-.12e-3);
1

%put %IsSASnumber(.N);
1

%put %IsSASnumber(.tryme);
0
```

My question is:

1. Is this regular expression covers all condition?
2. Is there a shorter or faster way to achieve this?

Ps: Assume the input is not empty.

Comment: an valid SAS number: I mean you can use it in data step like `input(variable,best.)` without  suspectful notes, warnings or errors.

Comment: Have a look at the `%IsNum()` macro detailed in this [Coders Corner 1 – PhamarSUG2005 paper](https://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug/2005/CodersCorner/cc01.pdf). It doesn't handle scientific notation though.

Comment: "Is a number" in what sense?  For use in generating SAS statements? `y=x=&mvar;` Or for use with the normal numeric informat? `y=input("&mvar",32.);`

Comment: Can you explain what rules your regex is implementing? It does not appear to support leading + sign.  It does not appear to support using the letter D in place of the letter E for exponential notation.  Try +1.2D1 which should be the number 120.

Comment: Do you want to take into account the settings of the MISSING statement which will impact which single letters can be used with to represent special missing values when using an informat?

Comment: @Tom I originally design this to validate a macro parameter is a number or not, thinking deeper now. Thank you for reminding me about the leading '+' and 'D' notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to support using the INPUT() function without generating error messages when the strings do not represent numbers then just use the `?` or `??` modifiers to suppress the errors.

Since the INPUT() function does not care if the width used on the informat specification is larger then the length of the string being read just use the maximum width the informat supports.  So just use:

```
number = input(variable,??32.);
```

You might also want to test the length of VARIABLE, the numeric informat can only handle strings up to 32 bytes long.  You might want to remove any leading spaces.

```
if length(left(variable)) <= 32 then number=input(left(variable),??32.);
```

If you want strings like "N" or "X" to be treated as meaning the special missing values `.N` and `.X` then make sure to tell SAS that in advance by using the global [MISSING statement](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_035/lestmtsglobal/n0ewjmosjtyjbtn1t5zabfkrof4f.htm). To support all 27 special missing values use a missing statement like this:

```
missing abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_ ;
```

If you want to treat '.N' as meaning `.N` instead of `.` then you will need to test for that string.  To test all of them you could use something like:

```
if missing(number) and length(variable)=2 and char(variable,1)='.'
  then number=input(char(variable,2),??32.)
;
```

Note: make sure to use the name of an INFORMAT when using the INPUT() function.  BEST is the name of a FORMAT (the name makes no sense as a name for an informat since there is only one way to represent a number as a number). If you use BEST as an INFORMAT SAS will just treat it as an alias for the normal numeric informat.

Comment: Thank you, Tom, `input` function with `?` or `??` modifier is a gode idea. I tried `%sysfunc(inputn(.tryme,??best.))` and got warning in log, could `inputn` function be used with `?` or `??` modifier?

Comment: You probably cannot use it with INPUTN() since it wants a STRING instead of an INFORMAT as the second option. So you cannot use it with %SYSFUNC().  Is it really that important to test the string with only macro logic? (PS BEST is the name of a FORMAT not an INFORMAT)

Answer (score 1):

The `%datatyp` macro can determine all of these, but it fails at `.N`. You can simplify your use case this way:

```
%macro IsSASnumber(number);
    %sysevalf(%datatyp(&number) = NUMERIC OR %sysfunc(prxmatch(/^\.[A-Z_]$|^\.$/i, &number)));
%mend;
```

This will match your numeric cases, and then you can match the `.` cases.

Comment: Note that %datatype() fails on values like `1.E2` which SAS data step happily takes as replacement for 100.

Comment: Bummer! I'm surprised it handles -.12e-3 but not 1.E2